# Calculate position and rotation of camera with mouse events

Tags: c++, opengl, math, 3d

My plan:

**1. Calculate mouse direction [x, y] [success]**

I my Mouse Move event:

```
int directionX = lastPosition.x - position.x;
int directionY = lastPosition.y - position.y;
```

**2. Calculate angles [theta, phi] [success]**

```
float theta = fmod(lastTheta + sensibility * directionY, M_PI);
float phi = fmod(lastPhi + sensibility * directionX * -1, M_PI * 2);
```

**Edit {**

**bug fix:**

```
float theta = lastTheta + sensibility * directionY * -1;
if (theta < M_PI / -2)theta = M_PI / -2;
else if (theta > M_PI / 2)theta = M_PI / 2;

float phi = fmod(lastPhi + sensibility * directionX * -1, M_PI * 2);
```

**}**

Now I have given **theta**, **phi**, the **centerpoint** and the **radius** and I want to calculate the **position** and the **rotation** [that the camera look at the centerpoint]

**3. Calculate position coordinates [X,Y,Z] [failed]**

```
float newX = radius * sin(phi) * cos(theta);
float newY = radius * sin(phi) * sin(theta);
float newZ = radius * cos(phi);
```

**Solution [by meowgoesthedog]:**

```
float newX = radius * cos(theta) * cos(phi);
float newY = radius * sin(theta);
float newZ = radius * cos(theta) * sin(phi);
```

**4. Calculate rotation [failed]**

```
float pitch = ?;
float yaw = ?;
```

**Solution [by meowgoesthedog]:**

```
float pitch = -theta;
float yaw = -phi;
```

Thanks for your solutions!

[image]

Comment: See [Trackball](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Object_Mouse_Trackball) also called "arcball"

Comment: @Ripi2 Thanks, I will read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt was almost (kinda) correct:

- As the diagram shows, in OpenGL the "vertical" direction is conventionally taken to be `Y`, whereas your formulas assume it is `Z`
- `phi` and `theta` are in the wrong order
- Very simple conversion: `yaw = -phi`, `pitch = -theta` (from the perspective of the camera)

Fixed formulas:

```
float position_X = radius * cos(theta) * cos(phi);
float position_Y = radius * sin(theta);
float position_Z = radius * cos(theta) * sin(phi);
```

(There may also be some sign issues with the mouse deltas but they should be easy to fix.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. pitch and yaw work, but the position doesn't, before the X axis worked, but now neither axis works.

Comment: @maxmister apologies - ironically I made the very mistake that I pointed out. Fixed

Comment: Thanks, now works x and z, but y works only to 70%, because if theta changes between 3.14159 and 3.13159, the model makes a huge step

Comment: @MaxMister `theta` (the angle to the XZ plane) is defined within the range `[-pi/2, pi/2]`. You are exceeding its range. (`phi` is in `[0, 2pi]`).